# Cocoa App windows have random focus

Tags: cocoa

I have a Cocoa App that has a MainMenu.nib that includes two Windows, but when I run the App it's random which of the windows has focus.  I'd like one of the windows to have focus.

The other thing I've noticed is that sometimes one or the other of the windows will be below the xcode window.  I would assume they would both be on top of xcode.

I don't see any options to set the window to have focus and it's odd that it's basically random which one has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had these problems too.
What I did was, I called makeKeyWindow on the window I wanted to have focus at the start in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Let's assume you had two windows in your AppDelegate and connected them to the windows in IB and you'd like to give the focus to the second window at launch.

The code had to be like this :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.secondWindow makeKeyWindow]; // If you wanted to give the second window the focus 
    //[self.window makeKeyWindow];
}
```

The order of the windows and which window has focus at start is not completely random.
The app automatically remembers the positions and order of all windows as you close your app and restores it as you start the application again.